# Regex get multiple sub string from a string (the main string contains new lines as well)

Tags: regex

I have pretty new to regular expression, so please allow any prematurity of my question :)
I am trying to find a `substring from a string (the string contains new line as well)`
I searched for similar questions in stackoverflow but none of those seem to answer what i am looking for.
Sample String

```
<td class="business-info">
<address>
104-59 118th Street<br />
Jamaica,
NY 
11419
</address>
</td>
```

What i am looking for is something like - 
`jamaica 11419`

- Edit
  I can select everything inside `<tr>` and `</tr>` with this
  `<tr>([^\n]*?\n+?)+?</tr>`
  But, if i try `<address>([^\n]*?\n+?)+?</address>` it seems not to work

Answer (score 0):

Please provide some more details to fully understand what you are trying to do; what you have tried and what kind of error or difficulty you are facing?

As to match your address tag -

```
<address>([\s\n\d\w\"\/\<\>\,\-]*)</address>
```

use this and see if it works.